# syntax error python in self. methode in class

Tags: python

why i have error in `self.words_lit`? 
`self.v_count` is the same but its okay

```
class word2vec():

    def __init__(self):
        self.n = settings['n']
        self.lr = settings['learning_rate']
        self.epochs = settings['epochs']
        self.window = settings['window_size']

    def generate_training_data(self, settings, data):
        # Find unique word counts using dictonary
        word_counts = defaultdict(int)
        for row in data:
            for word in row:
                word_counts[word] += 1

        self.v_count = len(word_counts.keys()

        self.words_list = list(word_counts.keys())

        self.word_index = dict((word, i) for i, word in enumerate(self.words_list))

        self.index_word = dict((i, word) for i, word in enumerate(self.words_list))

        training_data = []

        for i, word in enumerate(data):
            w_target = self.word2onehot(data[i])

            w_context = []

            for j in range(i - self.window, i + self.window+1):

                if j != i and j <= sent_len-1 and j >= 0:
                           w_context.append(self.word2onehot(data[j]))

            training_data.append([w_target, w_context])


        return np.array(training_data)

    def word2onehot(self, word):
        word_vec = [0 for i in range(0, self.v_count)]
        word_index = self.word_index[word]
        word_vec[word_index] = 1
        return word_vec

    def train(self, training_data):
        self.w1 = np.array(getW1)
        self.w2 = np.array(getW2)


        for i in range(self.epochs):
            self.loss = 0
            for w_t, w_c in training_data:
                y_pred, h, u = self.forward_pass(w_t)
                EI = np.sum([np.subtract(y_pred, word) for word in w_c], axis=0)

                self.backprop(EI, h, w_t)

                self.loss += -np.sum([u[word.index(1)] for word in w_c]) + len(w_c)

            print('Epoch:', i, "Loss:", self.loss)

    def forward_pass(self, x):
        h = np.dot(x, self.w1)
        u = np.dot(h, self.w2)
        y_c = self.softmax(u)
        return y_c, h, u

    def softmax(self, x):
        e_x = np.exp(x - np.max(x))
        return e_x / e_x.sum(axis=0)

    def backprop(self, e, h, x):
        dl_dw2 = np.outer(h, e)
        dl_dw1 = np.outer(x, np.dot(self.w2, e.T))

        self.w1 = self.w1 - (self.lr * dl_dw1)
        self.w2 = self.w2 - (self.lr * dl_dw2)

   def word_vec(self, word):
        w_index = self.word_index[word]
        v_w = self.w1[w_index]
        return v_w
```

error is

```
  File "<ipython-input-6-18d99c2172f1>", line 18
    self.words_list = list(word_counts.keys())
       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: you're missing closing parenthesis here: `self.v_count = len(word_counts.keys()`, one line before the error

Answer (score 2):

This line is missing the closing parenthesis:

```
self.v_count = len(word_counts.keys()
```

Often when you get a `SyntaxError` and the interpreter tells that the error is on for example line 18, the mistake is actually a missing comma, parentheses, or a quote on line 17.